# Alter Xcode 7 autofill behaviors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, logging

With the latest build, or maybe including the builds prior to beta 7.5 I just never noticed, I'm getting annoyed with a little autofill feature Apple implemented for `substitute tokens` and their objects when creating log messages. I haven't really noticed this with class methods or instance methods or autocompleting anything else really, so far.

Before, in Xcode 6, this would display:

[image: 1]

Ahhhhh, nice & crisp. As you can see, everything suffixing the user input is opportunity for autofill. All I had to do was press tab[enter] once to autofill 'error' and include the closing parenthesis, then it would automatically place my cursor *after* the closing parenthesis, hence *ALL* I had to do was type a `;` for that statement to be complete and I was happy :)

Now, this displays :

[image: 2]

Ehhhhh, troublesome & redundant. As you can see in this example, it includes an additional quotation mark. Now when I press tab to autofill 'error', it just autofills 'error' and places the cursor *before* the closing parenthesis. So it looks like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", error|)
```

And if I were to press tab to go to the next sub word that needs autocomplete it will just indent the closing parenthesis:

```
NSLog(@"%@", error   )
```

So essentially, I have to either move it with my mouse or press <kbd>→</kbd> and then and only then, I'll be able to enter a `;`. Side note - pressing <kbd>↵</kbd> to autofill results in the same behavior as described.

I am a fast typer, don't want to say my speed because I don't want it to rub off the wrong way but it's 70+wpm, so this irritates me, especially since I've been used to a way for so long. Any way to correct the behavior?

I have tried turning off `Enable type-over completions` in the Xcode preferences pane, but it still places the cursor before the closing parenthesis.

`printf` resorts to the same behavior with Xcode 7.5

Comment: I am assuming this is no longer an issue? Additionally, you do not need to type the closing paren, you can just hit `;` and it will auto complete the `)` for you as well.